# If $x\gt0$ prove that $\sqrt x\gt0$

Tags: inequality

I tried to prove by letting $x=y^2$  then $y^2\gt0$ and by taking the square root of both sides we have that $y\gt0$ and therefore $\sqrt x\gt0$. The problem mentions that a proof by contradiction can be done, but is this also acceptable?

Comment: Nothing in particular I just couldn't find a similar proof online.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}=y$ does not follow from $x=y^2$. Maybe just state how you know this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is fine, and the "other" proof is: if $\sqrt{x} = 0 \Rightarrow x = \left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = 0^2 = 0$, contradiction.